# Angular 5 update view

Tags: typescript, angular5

My app.component received date, but after user logout and another login - this data is still the same. Only after refresh page view show correct date.

How can I update date on the view when it was change on the database?

**app.component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getCurrentUser()
  }

getCurrentUser() {
      this.apiService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(
      data => { this.user = data },
      err => console.error(err)
    );   
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<p>{{user.name}}</p>
```

**api.service**

```
getCurrentUser() {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.path + '/curruser')
}
```

**auth.service**

```
loginUser(loginData) {
    this.http.post<loginUserData>(this.path + '/login', loginData).subscribe(res => {     
      this.saveToken(res.token)
      this.router.navigate(['/'])

    }, error => {
      console.log('error', error)
    })
  }
```

Comment: by calling getCurrentUser() again?

Comment: I try do this in login component but but view doesn't update.

Comment: Something must be wrong with your code then. If you don't post any, we can't help.

Comment: By **date** you meant **data**? What exactly you change on database that should affect view?

Comment: Post the code to your `apiService.getCurrentUser()`. I think you'll find the problem is in there. `.getCurrentUser()` is probably creating a new observable on each call, so you're only subscribing to the 1 observable created when you call `.getCurrentUser()` but not subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you didn't set an initial subscription for the actual updating of data in ngOnInit. Your subscription to the receiving of data makes sure that your application *receives* your data, but your app component doesn't know the data has been asynchronously updated. So you will need a separate subscription to *update* your data / view.

Do something like this:

```
userSubcription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    this.userSubscription = this.userService.dataReceived.subscribe(
    (user) => {
      this.user = user;
    });
    this.getCurrentUser();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.userSubscription.unsubscribe();
}

getCurrentUser() {
      this.apiService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(
      data => this.userService.dataReceived.next(data),
      err => console.error(err)
    );   
}
```

You'll need an additional userService to create a **Subject** that you can subscribe to.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code, but requesting current user from backend service only happens once, that won't update without re-requesting it.

If the ApiService is storing the current user, the user should be an observable that you can update:

```
user: new BehaviorSubject<User>();
```

Then in ApiService if user logs in or out:

```
login() {
  // omitted code that obtains user data in response
  // ...
  this.user.next(response.data);
}

logout() {
  this.user.next(null);
}
```

It's best to async pipe and let Angular handle subscriptions for you:

```
<p *ngIf="apiService.user | async as user">{{ user.name }}</p>
```

make sure you inject apiService as *public*

```
constructor(public apiService: ApiService) {}
```

Comment: Thank, but actually I'm a bit confuse where I need to place this code. I have two main services - aut.service where I have login/logout and api.service where I have among others: getCurrentUser() {return this.http.get<any>(this.path + '/curruser')}
Which function I need run i my component?

Comment: If you already have login/lout in aut.service, then you should add the user BehaviorSubject there. Why do you have an endpoint for current user and how does that work? Usually backend doesn't do anything with telling client a current user. Current user is referred to by a JWT token, or session state.